# NLog avoid writing a file after a certain size

Tags: .net, nlog

It happened that a file generated by NLog grew so much that leave the HD out of space.

Is it possible to limit the size of a file to prevent any other case like this one?
After the size is reached, stop logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at **[Archival Options](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target#archival-options)** and **[Size-based file archival](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target#size-based-file-archival)** in the NLog documentation for the File target.

You can use the `maxArchiveFiles` and `archiveAboveSize` parameters to keep the size of your log files within limits.

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
    ...
    archiveAboveSize="10240"
    maxArchiveFiles="10"
    ...
```